# converting a tmx file to *anything*

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, tmx

I have a tmx [file](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?7a0485e8a4f08d0d#/BEkzvwJmPNrFzWOwenZSayAwbFV5JgE1OAyCtZuStk=) with multiple languages defined for each term, and I can't find any way to convert it into individual anything -- gettext, php arrays, anything. My translation service does not let me download it in other formats (other than one per line plaintext without any keys, but that's a whole other problem).

I've only seen a po2tmx utility, not the other way around. Zend Framework 2's `Zend\I18n` documentation says it supports Tmx and Xliff, but it seems to.. not. I have no idea why, but

Is there any way at all I can convert this into some kind of usable format or do I have to end up writing some kind of weird thing that uses SimpleXML?

Comment: [http://www.wazzo.ca](http://www.wazzo.ca) allows the conversion of any TMX file to an HTML table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This converter](http://localise.biz/free/converter/tmx) can import TMX files containing up to two languages, and has various download options including PHP and PO files.

[The API](http://localise.biz/free/converter/api) will also convert a TMX file to PHP Zend format as follows (using command line cURL):

```
 $ curl --data-binary @file.tmx 'http://localise.biz/api/convert/tmx/file.phps'
```

Comment: It seems to only be taking the first language in the `<tu>` (which is en, then de), regardless of what I pass: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?23409f045e8ab674#9takIyLRsMx+AtsxKg4rivvpxKRpHXXyzqeo8GmpeXA=

Comment: I contacted them in any case, thanks for telling me about that. As much as I dislike depending on things that may or may not disappear, it looks like I have no other choice..